# R scraping a table with rvest, selectors not working

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the table in the link below:

https://www.pgatour.com/university/full-ranking.html

I would like the output to look like:

```
Rank     Player           University
1        Pierceson Coody  University of Texas
2        Sam Bennett      Texas A&M
```

The td class for the columns on the table are "rank", "player", "name" and when I try to set these as my selector I am getting an output of 'character (empty)' in the values section of Rstudio.

```
pga_url <- 'https://www.pgatour.com/university/full-ranking.html'

pgaU <- read_html(pga_url)
select <- '.name'

p <- html_nodes(pgaU,select) %>%
  html_text ()
```

The data is under a  HTML tag so idk if I'm using the write functions or selectors. Articles to scrape tables using wikipedia as examples were not helpful. I had not previously used the copy element/xpath/selector option on Inspect but haven't figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: Data is dynamically pulled from an API `https://statdata-api-prod.pgatour.com/api/clientfile/PGATourUniversityRankings?format=json&week=39`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access this element directly:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://statdata-api-prod.pgatour.com/api/clientfile/PGATourUniversityRankings?format=json&week=39")
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me where you go to in Inspect to find this api url. I found one that is similar under the elements tab but the link I found does not include the 
?format=json&week=39